# How to run a crontab each Sunday, except is it's first day of the month

Tags: cron

I'm running a weekly backup every Sunday and it's working fine.
Additionally I'm running a new monthly backup every 1st of each month, meaning if the 1st of the month is a Sunday, I got double backups. My crontab file :

```
* 0 1 * * backup_monthly.sh
* 0 2-31 * 0 backup_weekly.sh
```

My expectations are that backup_monthly is running the first of each month no matter what, and backup_weekly, every Sunday except Sunday 1st

Problem is that backup_weekly is running daily in this scenario

I did some research didn't find any occurrence with a negative condition.

Thanks if you have some idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
0 0 * * * ([ "$(date +\%d)" = "01" ] || [ "$(date +\%a)" = "Sun" ]) && backup_monthly.sh
```

**What does it mean?**

- `0 0 * * *` means the cron job will run at 12:00 AM (midnight) every day.
- `([ "$(date +\%d)" = "01" ] || [ "$(date +\%a)" = "Sun" ])` consists of two parts.

  - `[ "$(date +\%d)" = "01" ]` checks if the current day of the month is `01`.
  - `[ "$(date +\%a)" = "Sun" ]` checks if the current day of the week is `Sun`.
- `&& backup_monthly.sh` specifies the command that will be executed.

> So, the cron job is scheduled to run every day at 12:00
> AM, but the backup command will be executed only if it's
> either the `1st day` of the month or `Sunday`.

Comment: Although, since I want weekly not running when monthly is scheduled, I will try with this modification [ "$(date +\%d)" != "01" ] and apply it on backup_weekly.sh

Answer (score 0):

Use this

`0 0 * * 0 [ "$(date +\%d -d tomorrow)" != "01" ] && your-command`